# What is the purpose for std::construct_at to cast through a pointer to volatile when using placement new?

Tags: c++, casting, volatile, object-construction

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at), `std::construct_at(T*p, Args&&... args)` is equivalent to

```
return ::new (const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const volatile void*>(p)))
    T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

What is the need/purpose for the cast 'through' `const volatile void*`? In other words, why is `construct_at` not simply equivalent to

```
return ::new (static_cast<void*>(p))
    T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Under which conditions would this latter code cause undesirable behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::construct_at` accepts as `T` any type... which may have cv-qualifiers.

Meanwhile, `static_cast` [may not cast away constness](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#1). The version you propose would fail for

```
const foo * ptr = get_mem();
ptr = std::construct_at(ptr); // Error here when naively static casting to void*
```

But `static_cast` *may* add cv-qualifiers. So in order to be generic, the version that is standardized avoids this problem. It static casts to the most cv-qualified version of of a `void` pointer, and then removes those qualifiers.

Comment: Why not just `(void*)p`?

Comment: @Ayxan - C-style cast... ewww

Comment: So the naive version will cause a compiler error, nothing more serious (a run-time error or worse undefined behaviour)?

Comment: @Walter it would compile for types without `const volatile` and cause a compile time error for cv qualified types.

Comment: If these casts get any longer, I shall have to buy a bigger monitor.